# Is it possible to post an announcement via the Yammer API?

Tags: yammer

It appears that only Yammer announcements get pushed to mobile. Is it possible to post an announcement to a group (or Company Wide) via the Yammer API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it setting the broadcast parameter to true, as described on https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/messages-json-post

Comment: Link only answers are not quite recommended. Please provide some examples with explanation.

Comment: Also, I've tried this and unless you can confirm otherwise, it appears to add a standard 'update' rather than an announcement (with separate title and body), and notifies all users within the group.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but the following API call seems to create an announcement:

```
yam.platform.request({
url: "messages.json",
method: "POST",
data: {
    "body": "Example message",
    "log_data[publisher_type]": "yam.ui.publisher.global.AnnouncementPublisher",
    "log_data[publisher_source]": "group",
    "log_data[number_of_recipients]": "1",
    "invited_user_ids": "",
    "skip_body_notifications": "true",
    "group_id": "54321",
    "is_rich_text": "true",
    "message_type": "announcement",
    "title": "Example title"
},
success: function () {
    // Do something else
},
error: function (error) {
    console.log(error);
}});
```